# TypeScript omit fields from super extends interface

Tags: typescript, interface, mysql2

I have a DTO:

```
export interface MyDTO extends mysql.RowDataPacket {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  ... 
}
```

And another DTO to create objects where I don't want the id field:

```
export interface CreateMyDTO extends Omit<MyDTO, "id"> {}
```

But I have a problem with the extended class in `MyDTO`. In `CreateMyDTO`  I don't want to get `mysql.RowDataPacket` properties.

There is a way to ignore `mysql.RowDataPacket` in `CreateMyDTO`  ? In this child I just want `MyDTO` properties except the id.

Comment: if you dont want fields from mysql.RowDataPacke what you can do is change the structure of the code to have "base interface" with the fields you want to share and extend from that on both objects

Comment: You should definitely refactor as @JonathanAlfaro recommends.  If for some reason you can't it might be possible to tease apart `MyDTO` into those properties added explicitly and those it inherits from `RowDataPacket`, but this is like unbaking a cake and depends heavily on the recipe, er, the definition of `RowDataPacket`.  Can you give a type definition of `RowDataPacket` or replace it with a type that you define here?  If the question depends on mysql or mysql2 in an important way, you might want to tag it as such.

Comment: @jcalz yup RowDataPacket is an interface from mysql2